# How do I run a .war file with tomcat/maven?

Tags: java, maven, installation, pom.xml

I'm new to tomcat and maven configuration. I was given a single .war that has all the dependencies in it. I'm trying to figure out how to run the war file on a given port configured using a pom.xml file

I tried mvn tomcat:run-war where the .war file lives but it obviously needs a pom.xml How can I configure this to be able to run this?

Comment: You should read more about what maven and tomcat is..

Answer (score 0):

If you have already compiled project with all the dependencies in it then it has nothing to do with maven (because it's a tool for building projects from source code).

In order to deploy a war file you should install standalone tomcat on your system and drop the war file into webapps directory in the tomcat installation home folder, then (re)start tomcat. Give it 20-30 seconds to launch and open http://localhost:8080/war-file-name-without-dot-war in your browser, if everything went right then you will see the deployed application.

Comment: ok did that. getting a 404 not found when we go to the /war-file-name-without-dot-war. tomcat server is running though.

Comment: It means that either you dropped the war file in a wrong directory or tomcat failed to deploy the war for some reasons. Check out catalina.out log file inside tomcat's logs directory for any errors.